# `initialize': getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution (SocketError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I am unable to `rails s` all of a sudden. I did not update my ruby or gems.

Here is the error log I'm seeing:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    41: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    40: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    39: from /home/username/Documents/heroku/appname/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    38: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
    37: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
    36: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    35: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    34: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    33: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    32: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    31: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    30: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    29: from /home/username/Documents/heroku/appname/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    27: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    26: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    25: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    24: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    23: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    22: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    21: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    20: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    18: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    17: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    16: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    15: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    14: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    13: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    12: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    11: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
    10: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
     9: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:73:in `run'
     8: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:186:in `run'
     7: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/single.rb:98:in `run'
     6: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:153:in `load_and_bind'
     5: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `parse'
     4: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `each'
     3: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:106:in `block in parse'
     2: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in `add_tcp_listener'
     1: from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in `new'
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution (SocketError)
```

Here is the github ticket: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1909

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: @anothermh when I run `./bin/spring stop`, it returns `Spring is not running`

Answer (score 3):

I had to use bundle exec puma -b 'tcp://0.0.0.0:8080' -b to avoid this issue launching in AWS